# Groovy, App Engine, and the 3000 file limit

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy

Firstly, I'm new to groovy as of yesterday, so what I say could be incorrect.

In groovy, every time you create a closure in your code, it creates a separate .class file like this `Test$_closure1.class`.  I could easily have 3000 different closures throughout my project, which would thus push me over the 3000 file limit on App Engine.

It only creates the class files if I actually compile my Groovy files, which I want to do because I have existing Java classes that I want to be able to call Groovy classes from.

Is there a way I can lessen the number of files it will need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a library out of those classes -> essentially making a `jar` file. Once you have a jar (a zip for all classes) its treated as one file.